# Log4j - How to scan for log4j usages in maven projects along with project name?

Tags: maven, log4j

As part Log4jshell problem, we are trying to analyze which projects use which version of Log4j. I did try the following maven commands

```
mvn dependency:list | grep log4j
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose | grep log4
```

But it lists information only like this

```
mvn dependency:tree | grep log4
[INFO] \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.13.1:provided
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.13.1:provided
[INFO] |  |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:provided
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.13.1:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.13.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.13.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.13.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:jar:2.1.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:jar:2.1.8.RELEASE:compile
```

I cannot find which project in our workspace it points to. Can anyone please help on this?

Note: There are several maven projects and there is a parent pom.xml for all the pom.xml files. So want to identify which maven projects are using log4j along with the name.

Comment: Print out the whole tree instead of filtering the lines via grep...the tree shows where the root of a dependency is...

Comment: grep commands lists if log4j is used or not. Format for the command to see which project or third party library is using it what actually needed. Trying grep different grep commands but not so lucky till now.

Comment: Executing the command without grep is listing the entire dependency tree. Since the workspace uses several hundred of libraries, it is not so easy to manually scan the dependency tree.

Comment: Yes I know that it's not easy. But you wanted to know where it's coming from... so you have to go that path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ***includes*** option

```
 mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.apache.logging.log4j
```

example output:

```
[INFO] com.test:test:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO]       \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO]          \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.14.1:compile
[INFO]             \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.14.1:compile
```

[documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html#includes)

Comment: Do you any tool which can help to find which projects are using a specific artifact?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. Yes it did answer my question. I used the command below and got the result.

mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.apache.logging.log4j -DoutputFile=`pwd`/maven-report-log4j.txt -DappendOutput=true